# pthread_mutex_t init error

Tags: initialization, pthreads, mutex

I am using xcode 2.4.1 on tiger. When i do below everything is ok. when i do

```
pthread_mutex_t mute;
ImageMan()
{
    dibSize=0;
    mute  = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
}
```

I get these two errors

```
error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
error: expected `;' before '{' token
```

I dont know why. However if i do pthread_mutex_t mute  = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; it works fine. Why?

-edit-
I havent ran it but this seems to compile. Why? huh?

```
    pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    mute = mutex;
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` is a constant initializer, valid when in initialization only. It is a macro that doesn't necessarily expand to an integral type.

Your `mute=mutex;` is invalid- instead you should use:

```
pthread_mutex_init(&mute, NULL);
```

or if you're allocating mutexes dynamically:

```
m = malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t)));
pthread_mutex_init(m, NULL);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mute = (pthread_mutex_t)PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

This is an another solution for this error.

Comment: Always try to give some explanation of answer.